# Qt QString Q_PROPERTY causing SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, segmentation-fault, qstring

I ran into this problem the other day - caught me by surprise and has halted my testing. I'm developing a feature outside of my normal application and I ran into an issue with a Q_PROPERTY that I can't seem to figure out. I've simplified the situation down to bare bones which still replicates the SIGSEGV.  My code has a comment switch block that includes or removes an additional Q_PROPERTY "prop2"  When I have just one property "prop1" I don't get the seg fault.  When I add the additional property "prop2" I get the seg fault.  I've included everything - including a dump of gdb.  Any help/advice would be most appreciated.

System: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (the greatest OS on Earth)
Qt: 4.8 (as installed with apt-get install qt-sdk)

file: MyObject.hpp

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_HPP
#define MYOBJECT_HPP

#include <QObject>

class MyObject : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString prop1 READ prop1 WRITE setProp1 RESET resetProp1)
    //* add/remove comment
    Q_PROPERTY(QString prop2 READ prop2 WRITE setProp2 RESET resetProp2) 
    // end */
private:
    QString m_prop1;
    //* add/remove comment
    QString m_prop2;
    // end */
public:
    MyObject(QObject * parent = 0):QObject(parent){
        resetProp1();
        //* add/remove comment
        resetProp2();
        // end */
    }
    virtual ~MyObject(){ }
    QString prop1() const{
        return m_prop1;
    }
    QString setProp1(const QString& prop1){
        m_prop1 = prop1;
    }
    void resetProp1(){
        setProp1("reset");
    }
    //* add/remove comment
    QString prop2() const{
        return m_prop2;
    }
    QString setProp2(const QString& prop2){
        m_prop2 = prop2;
    }
    void resetProp2(){
        setProp2("reset");
    }
    // end */
};

#endif
```

file: main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MyObject.hpp"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyObject obj;
    return app.exec();
}
```

file: CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test)
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
QT4_WRAP_CPP(test_MOC_SOURCES 
    MyObject.hpp
)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})

add_executable(test 
    main.cpp
    ${test_MOC_SOURCES}
)

target_link_libraries(test ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

gdb output:

```
Reading symbols from /home/me/temp/string_seg_test/build/test...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/me/temp/string_seg_test/build/test 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffe7fc6700 (LWP 9297)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe77c5700 (LWP 9298)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe6354700 (LWP 9299)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6d00bbd in QString::operator=(QString const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6d00bbd in QString::operator=(QString const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#1  0x0000000000401b43 in MyObject::setProp2 (this=0x7fffffffe11000, prop2=...)
    at /home/me/temp/string_seg_test/src/MyObject.hpp:39
#2  0x0000000000401b7f in MyObject::resetProp2 (this=0x7fffffffe11000)
    at /home/me/temp/string_seg_test/src/MyObject.hpp:42
#3  0x000000000040197b in MyObject::MyObject (this=0x7fffffffe11000, parent=0x0)
    at /home/me/temp/string_seg_test/src/MyObject.hpp:21
#4  0x000000004017ee00 in ?? ()
#5  0x007fffffffe23800 in ?? ()
#6  0x0000010040154b00 in ?? ()
#7  0x000000004021b000 in ?? ()
#8  0x000000007ef92000 in ?? ()
#9  0x000000007ef9b000 in ?? ()
#10 0x0000000060310000 in ?? ()
#11 0x007ffff7d9a9d000 in ?? ()
#12 0x00000000604d2000 in ?? ()
#13 0x007fffffffe23000 in ?? ()
#14 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple problem. Your setter methods return `QString`, but you never return anything from those methods. Thus a crash. The setters should have the following signature: `void setPropx(const QString &);`

Your compiler most likely has warned you about this. Thus, the lesson is: do **not** ignore compiler warnings. Understand their meaning.

On the other hand, you've left in a *lot* of irrelevant stuff. Had you been methodically stripping things line-by-line, you would have eventually arrived at a much smaller, single file example. The `QObject` and application instances are not needed, neither is the indirection of the `resetProp()`, nor do the getters make any difference.

The final two steps of minimization should have been:

```
// Step N-1
#include <QString>
class C {
    QString m_prop1, m_prop2;
public:
    C() { setProp1("reset"); setProp2("reset"); }
    QString setProp1(const QString& prop1) { m_prop1 = prop1; }
    QString setProp2(const QString& prop2) { m_prop2 = prop2; }
} c;
int main(int, char **) {
    return 0;
}

// Step N
#include <QString>
class C {
    QString m_prop1;
public:
    C() { setProp1("reset"); setProp1("reset"); }
    QString setProp1(const QString& prop1) { m_prop1 = prop1; }
} c;
int main(int, char **) {
    return 0;
}
```

By this point you could have probably noticed what was wrong.

Everything should be in a single file. The separate header etc. are just a distraction that makes your question longer. This is what you should have posted :)